# Inner join help in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MsgID, Name FROM tbl_message INNER JOIN tbl_user on tbl_message.UserID = tbl_user.UserID WHERE OrgID ='1' order by MsgID
```

I have a message table

```
msgid  msg   userid  Orgid
24     Hi     2        1
25     hsa    4        1
```

User table

```
userid     Name    Orgid
2          cas      1
4          asd      1
```

I want to get the name from user table. I am doing inner join to get it but I am getting error. what is wrong with the query. Error is OrgID is ambiguous

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given query:

```
SELECT message.msg, message.msgid, message.userid, 
message.orgid, user.username, user.orgid
FROM user INNER JOIN message 
ON user.userid = message.userid 
WHERE  message.orgid='1' 
order by  message.msgid
```

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you told us what the error is.  Looking at your query, two errors I can see are:

- There's a stray comma after `SELECT MsgID` which should be removed.
- The `WHERE OrganisationID ='1'` part of the statement seems to reference a column `OrganisationID` which doesn't exist.  Maybe change it to `Orgid`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MsgID FROM tbl_message INNER JOIN tbl_user on tbl_message.UserID = tbl_user.UserID WHERE OrgID ='1' order by MsgID
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work, in your code Orgid in where condition is ambigious

```
SELECT 
   msgid
FROM 
   tbl_message
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_message.UserID = tbl_user.UserID
WHERE 
   tbl_message.Orgid = 1
   AND tbl_user.Orgid = 1
ORDER BY msgid
```